# Use of two different database for the spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch-admin

*I want to configure two different databases in spring admin batch job. But while running the application only "POSTGRES" database is getting configure. Is it possible to configure 2 diff DB for the spring batch application. 
I have added properties for both DB. It is getting configured and running the application. But when i tried to fetch the data from different DB(secondary). So it is not able to map the tables

```
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/glow
batch.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
batch.jdbc.user=postgres
batch.jdbc.password=postgres
travel.batch.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
travel.batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/travel
travel.batch.jdbc.user=root
travel.batch.jdbc.password=root
```

I want to configure and connect to both database fetch the data from both DB for different batch job in spring admin batch job project*

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Not able two map tables of secondary database, but i am not getting error while configuring the second database


Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'glow.pod_notification' doesn't exist

Comment: Can you see the table in an admin view or something like that ? Are you sure that it exists ?

Comment: I did'nt get by admin view, the table exist in another "TRAVEL" database, 
And only by default 
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/glow
batch.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
batch.jdbc.user=postgres
batch.jdbc.password=postgres

the above properties are getting enabled as it is starting by "batch.jdbc..."

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel  Is it possible to use two database for spring batch admin ??

Comment: I don't really see why it wouldn't work. Does it work if you remove the `glow` and only keep `travel` ? Do you have the same error ?

Comment: if i replace travel instead of glow so it will work fine, as it only going to configure " batch.jdbc.url " properties not others

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In spring batch application two database are not configured at a time only 1db can connect, though it can multiple properties to connect to database at a time only one can connect and it is verified. In spring boot application it is possible to connect multiple database at a time but not in spring batch.

Comment: Just do it how Spring-Boot does it. All boot gives you is auto-configuration, so you can manually do the same thing in a non-boot app.

Comment: @jinit bansod can i retrieve data from one db and save it in another db using springbatch?